# How to use model events with query builder in laravel

Tags: events, laravel, model, query-builder

I'm using model events such as static::saving, static::saved, etc in my models' static function boot method, and that works great when users save new posts, but when I do something like this:

```
$post::where('id', $post_id)->update(array('published'=>1));
```

Updating in this way does not run those model events. My current solution is to just not use this method of updating and instead do:

```
$post = Post::find($post_id);
$post->published = 1;
$post->save();
```

But is there any way to make the model events work with the first example using query builder?

Comment: Any particular reason why not to use Eloquent for this?

Comment: I'm fine with using Eloquent, it's just that I know there are some places in my code where I've used query builder and will have to change them. And I'll have to remember not to use query builder for these types of things in the future.

Comment: If I understand it correctly, using Eloquent always requires an extra database call (one to select the post, then one to update it). I wanted to avoid that if possible...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Model events will not work with a query builder at all.

One option is to use [Event listener](http://laravel.com/docs/events#basic-usage) for `illuminate.query` from `/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php`. But this will work only for `saved`, `updated` and `deleted`. And requires a bit of work, involving processing the queries and looking for SQL clauses, not to mention the DB portability issues this way.

Second option, which you do not want, is Eloquent. You should still consider it, because you already have the events defined. This way you can use also events ending with `-ing`.

Comment: Well, I guess I'll just be sticking to Eloquent then, thanks.